# Remove CSS box shadow Chrome/Safari, Firefox already ok

Tags: html, css

Been playing with CSS on my WP-based [site](http://francescomarcellino.com/), yet really cannot figure out how to solve a small shadow rendering issue that only appears while browsing with either Chrome or Safari (with Firefox is fine).

Within the footer cookie bar, the "Got it" button should not present any shadow effect at all, in any browser. Instead, it appears to [show an outer shadow](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6444926/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-23%20at%2012.01.13.png) fx that I would like to remove.

Tried to inspect the element with Firebug, yet still can't understand what's the CSS that is creating this. Any lead? Thank you!

Comment: You do have a `-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6); ` applied in your CSS.

Comment: Remove -webkit-box-shadow in cli-style.css

Answer (score -1):

just add `box-shadow:none` and shadow will disappear

it is because one of your style named

```
.cli-plugin-button, .cli-plugin-button:visited
```

has `-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);` this is why it is appearing in chrome and safari only.

Answer (score -1):

Remove or override the style for

```
.cli-plugin-button, .cli-plugin-button:visited
```

class to not include -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6)

that would get rid of the box shadow that you are seeing